# error con plantillas y metodo

Tags: c++, template

Hola estoy haciendo un codigo con plantillas, y cuando lo compilaba me sale el siguiente error :

```
    main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
    main.cpp:41:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '+': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
    main.cpp:42:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '-': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
    main.cpp:43:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '*': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
    main.cpp:44:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '/': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
    main.cpp:45:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '=': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
    main.cpp:46:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '<': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
    main.cpp:47:28: error: ‘class number<char, 0, 10>’ has no member named ‘make_op’
             case '>': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
                                ^~~~~~~
```

El codigo en el main que menciona es el siguiente:

```
    switch(operacion){                                      // ejecutamos las operaciones

        case '+': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
        case '-': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
        case '*': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
        case '/': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
        case '=': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
        case '<': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
        case '>': number_T.make_op(operacion);break;
    }
```

Y el fichero que contiene el objeto y el metodo es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
template < class T, size_t N, size_t B >

class number{

    private:
    T* digitos; 
    int index;
    int base;
    int val1,val2;
    int final=0;
    int size;
    public:



    void s_base(int i){
        base=i;

    }       
    void set_vals(int a, int b){
        val1=a;
        val2=b;

    }


    number(T valor):digitos(NULL){
       resize_v(N);
       int sz = sizeof(valor);
       resize_v(sz);       
    }


    void resize_v(int sz){

        digitos = new T [sz];
        size=sz;
        index = sz -1;
    }


    int longitud(int number) const{

            return ceil(log(number)/log(base));  // usa la libreria math.h

    }



    void set_base(int n ){
        if(n>=base){
            int result = n / base;             // obtenemos el valor resultado de la divicion, para la llamada recursiva
            int rest = n % base;               // obtenemos el resto, para guardarlo en el vector
            if(rest > 9 ){                  // en caso que el numero dado sea mayor que 9, hay que representarlo en caracteres alfabeticos
                rest+=55;                    // si rest = 10, 10 + 55 = 65 === 'A'
                digitos[index]=(char)rest;
            }
            else{
                rest+=48;
                digitos[index]=(char)rest;
            }
            index--;                        // disminuimos el indice del vector
            set_base(result);               // llamada recursiva
        }


        else{
            if(n > 9 ){                  // en caso que el numero dado sea mayor que 9, hay que representarlo en caracteres alfabeticos
                n+=55;                    // si rest = 10, 10 + 55 = 65 === 'A'
                digitos[index]=(char)n;
            }
            else{
                n+=48;
                digitos[index]=(char)n;
            }
            digitos[index]=n;                 // al llegar al ultimo valor en el que no se pueda dividir por la base, se inserta en la posicion mas
            index=0;                        // significativa
        }
    }

    void make_op(char op){

        int result=0;
        switch(op){

        case '+':  result=val1+val2;resize_v(longitud(result));set_base(result);break;
        case '-':  result=val1-val2;resize_v(longitud(result));set_base(result);break;
        case '*':  result=val1*val2;resize_v(longitud(result));set_base(result);break;
        case '/':  result=val1/val2;resize_v(longitud(result));set_base(result);break;
        case '=':  val1==val2 ? cout<<"Son iguales"<<endl : cout<<"No son iguales"<<endl;break;
        case '<':  val1<val2 ? cout<<"El primer valor es menor"<<endl : cout<<"El primer valor es mayor";break;
        case '>':  val1>val2 ? cout<<"El primer valor es mayor"<<endl : cout<<"El primer valor es menor"<<endl;break;

        }

    }
    int get_result(){
        if(index>0){

            int result=int(digitos[index]);
            result>=55 ? result-55 : result-48;
            int a=pow(base,index);
            index--;

            final=get_result()+ result*a;

            return final;
        }

    }


    ostream& write(ostream& os)const{

        for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
            cout << " | " << digitos[i];
        }
        cout<< endl;

    }   
};
```

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es `number_T`? La plantilla tiene 3 parámetros... ¿qué valores tienen en ese tipo?

Comment: number_t se le llama al constructor de esta forma number_t <char,0,10>numero ("0");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa plantilla hace aguas por todos lados:

**Constructor**

El constructor de la plantilla se supone que recibe un valor... pero no hace nada con dicho valor. Yo esperaría que lo almacenase en `digitos`, pero no.

```
number(T valor):digitos(NULL){
   resize_v(N);
   int sz = sizeof(valor);
   resize_v(sz);       
}
```

Lo único que hace con `valor` es llamar a `sizeof` ¿para qué? esa operación no tiene sentido ya que `sizeof` no te va a decir cuantos dígitos tiene el número. `sizeof` se evalua en tiempo de compilación y te dice cuántos bytes ocupa el tipo en cuestión.

- Si `T == int`, `sizeof(valor) == 4` y da igual el contenido de `valor`
- Si `T == char[],`sizeof(valor) == strlen(valor)+1`. Tampoco obtienes el número de dígitos
- Si `T == char`, `sizeof(valor) == 1`
- ...

Teniendo en cuenta que `T` se utiliza como tipo base del array vemos que solo tendría sentido que `T == char`, pero en ese caso solo podremos meter un único dígito en el objeto... no tiene sentido.

**Fugas de memoria**

Cada vez que llamas a `resize_v` creas una fuga de memoria. **no liberas la memoria** antes de llamar a `new`:

```
void resize_v(int sz){

    digitos = new T [sz]; // <<--- que pasa con la reserva anterior?
    size=sz;
    index = sz -1;
}
```

**Te falta return**

Si una función tiene un tipo de retorno, necesariamente **debe tener un return**. En tu caso eso no se cumple en la función `write`:

```
ostream& write(ostream& os)const{

    for(int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
        cout << " | " << digitos[i];
    }
    cout<< endl;
                              // <<--- Aqui falta un return
}
```

**Tipos sin uso**

La plantilla tiene 3 parámetros. ¿Para qué sirve cada uno?

`T` se usa como base para el array `digitos`. ¿Tiene sentido que `digitos` sea un array de double? a mi me parece que no. También se usa en el constructor, aquí si podría tener sentido pero solo para poder pasar de `T` a un array de enteros o caracteres. Desde mi punto de vista `T` no debería ser un parámetro de la clase sino del constructor:

```
template<class T>
number(T valor)
{
   // ...
}
```

`N` se utiliza para determinar el tamaño del array `digitos`, pero solo temporalmente porque después se redimensiona con otro tamaño distinto. ¿Para qué sirve `N` entonces?

`B` directamente no tiene uso, luego es un parámetro que parece sobrar.

Resumiendo, con el código que presentas no hay razón para que `number` sea una plantilla.

```
class number{
private:
    char* digitos; 
    int index;
    int base;
    int val1,val2;
    int final=0;
    int size;

public:
    template<class T>
    number(T valor)
    {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Pero claro, no termino de entender qué utilidad pretende cubrir esta clase. Es probable que debas replantear tu pregunta para afinar mejor las respuestas.

Comment: hola, el tema de la plantilla es porque es una practica de la universidad. Nos pide basicamente que se le pase un tipo de dato(para el array), una longitud (del numero que se va a guardar digito por digito en el array) y por ultimo la base en la que va a estar dicho numero. Probablemente tenga muchos fallos, sobretodo por dos elementos de la plantilla que son de tipo size_t, que basicamente me obliga a introducirle un valor a mano he tenido muchos problemas con esto porque no lo he sabido manejar, y tampoco me enseñan como....

Comment: Si tienes que pasarle el tamaño vía parámetro de la plantilla entonces no tienes que usar `int * digitos` sino `int[N] digitos`. Te están pidiendo un array de tamaño fijo o, si tiene que ser dinámico, el tamaño no va a cambiar, será **siempre** `int * digitos = new int[N]`

Comment: si, el tamaño es dinamico, pero aun asi, no se porque me da el error...

Comment: @k1k4ss0 Ignoro por qué tienes el error que comentas. Es probable que tengas errores antes del que citas y que a partir de ahí el compilador se lie. Como te he comentado, tu plantilla no tiene ahora mismo ni pies ni cabeza. La función `make_op` debería recibir dos objetos de tipo `number` y operar con ellos... ¿Qué pinta ahí `val1` y `val2`? ¿No se supone que estas almacenando los valores en `digitos`?

Comment: pues un dia me levante lo compile y por la cara no dio el error....